# Convert weight, the value doesn't display

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating this simple weight converter and I have a small problem with the display of the value in the text field. I would like the result came back in the field where I type the kg.

What am I doing wrong?

At the moment I am trying to convert kg to grams

```js
function submitF() {
  const option1 = document.querySelector("#option1").value;
  const option2 = document.querySelector("#option2").value;
  var inputField = document.querySelector("#weightarea").value;
  var kgToGram = inputField * 1000;



  if (option1 === "Kilo" && option2 === "Grams") {
    inputField = kgToGram;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>

  <input id="weightarea" type="number" placeholder="value.....">
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitF()"><br>
  <select id="option1">
    <option>Kilo</option>
    <option>Pounds</option>
    <option>Grams</option>
  </select>

  <p>to</p>

  <select id="option2">
    <option>Kilo</option>
    <option>Pounds</option>
    <option>Grams</option>
  </select>




  <script src="java2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: inputField = kgToGram;   not correct way to assign  value to a field. there someone answered, gl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputfield = document.querySelector("#weightarea").value;
inputfield = kgToGram;
```

...is not the same thing as...

```
document.querySelector("#weightarea").value = kgToGram;
```

I believe you're expecting `inputfield` to be a reference, but this is not the case. Your current code simply declares a variable and initializes it with the value of the input.

The second example above actually sets the value of the input.

See below:

```js
function submitF() {
  const option1 = document.querySelector("#option1").value;
  const option2 = document.querySelector("#option2").value;
  var inputField = document.querySelector("#weightarea").value;
  var kgToGram = inputField * 1000;

  if (option1 === "Kilo" && option2 === "Grams") {
    document.querySelector("#weightarea").value = kgToGram;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>

  <input id="weightarea" type="number" placeholder="value.....">
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitF()"><br>
  <select id="option1">
    <option>Kilo</option>
    <option>Pounds</option>
    <option>Grams</option>
  </select>

  <p>to</p>

  <select id="option2">
    <option>Kilo</option>
    <option>Pounds</option>
    <option>Grams</option>
  </select>




  <script src="java2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the value of the input field after you do the conversion.  Instead you are simply telling the `inputField` javascript variable to hold the value of whatever `kgToGram` is.

```
function submitF() {
  const option1 = document.querySelector("#option1").value;
  const option2 = document.querySelector("#option2").value;
  var inputField = document.querySelector("#weightarea").value; // retrieving the value at that point-in-time.  Not the entire element.
  var kgToGram = inputField * 1000;



  if (option1 === "Kilo" && option2 === "Grams") {
    // wrong ... inputField = kgToGram;
    document.querySelector("#weightarea").value = kgToGram; // re-assign the value of the input element
  }


}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark an answer as accepted so that the question can be seen as answered.

Comment: @JakubKlos M12 Bennett is talking about the advice given [in the help center regarding what to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).